# Имитация множественного наследования

Tags: наследование, typescript, множественное-наследование, mixins, прототипное-наследование

Есть класс и функция-конструктор. Делается попытка реализовать класс, являющийся чем-то типа потомка обоих. Точнее, методы из прототипа функции-конструктора копируются в прототип класса-потомка, унаследованный от класса.

Да, я понимаю, что это не полноценное наследование, но для решения задачи этого хватает.

Проблема в другом. Как заставить тайпскрипт воспринимать копируемые методы?

```
class First {
  someMethod() {
    console.log('someMethod from First');
  }
}

function Second() {
  console.log('Second');
}

Second.prototype.doSmth = function () { 
  console.log('doSmth from Second');
}

interface IBoth {
  someMethod()
  doSmth()
}

class Both extends First /* implements IBoth */ {
  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor of Both');
    super();
    Second.call(this);
  }
}

for (let key in Second.prototype) {
  Both.prototype[key] = Second.prototype[key];
}
```

На самом деле, надо обеспечить видимость методов ещё на уровень дальше

```
class Final extends Both {
  doIt() {
    this.someMethod();
    //this.doSmth(); // Надо заставить видеть метод тут
    (this as any as IBoth).doSmth(); // Компилируется, но это ужас
  }
}
```

если при этом методы не будут видны из самого `Both`, то это годится.

Вот что я уже пробовал:

1. При попытке написать

   ```
   class Both extends First implements IBoth {
   ```

   возникает ошибка, что я не реализую методы интерфейса.
2. При переименовании `Both` в `_Both` и использовании

   ```
   var Both = _Both as typeof _Both;
   ```

   всё остаётся как было, что логично, поскольку тут никак не используется `First`.
3. При переименовании `Both` в `_Both` и использовании

   ```
   var Both = _Both as typeof IBoth;
   ```

   говорит, что не может найти имя `IBoth`.

Пробовал ещё несколько вариантов, но они совсем бредовые.
Что ещё можно сделать?

---

Попробовать можно тут: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground
**[Полный код для проверки](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=class%20First%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20someMethod()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('someMethod%20from%20First')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20Second()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log('Second')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0ASecond.prototype.doSmth%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20console.log('doSmth%20from%20Second')%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20IBoth%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20someMethod()%0D%0A%20%20doSmth()%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Both%20extends%20First%20%2F*%20implements%20IBoth%20*%2F%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20console.log('constructor%20of%20Both')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Second.call(this)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(let%20key%20in%20Second.prototype)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20Both.prototype%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20Second.prototype%5Bkey%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Final%20extends%20Both%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20doIt()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.someMethod()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.doSmth()%3B%20%2F%2F%20How%20to%20make%20this%20call%20threated%20as%20correct%3F%0D%0A%20%20%20%20(this%20as%20any%20as%20IBoth).doSmth()%3B%20%2F%2F%20That%20compiles%2C%20but%20it's%20awfull%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A(new%20Final).doIt()%3B)**

Запустить (код из правой панели) после добавления строки:

```
(new Final).doIt();
```

Вывод при запуске при раскомментированной строке `this.doSmth();`

```
constructor of Both
Second
someMethod from First
doSmth from Second
doSmth from Second
```

---

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34232656/imitate-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34232656/4928642

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Интерфейс вообще не нужен, нужно просто объявить прототипное поле с нужным типом:

```
doSmth: () => void
```

Она видима как свойство, а не как метод, но это непринципиально.

Полный код:

```
class First {
  someMethod() {
    console.log('someMethod from First');
  }
}

function Second() {
  console.log('Second');
}

Second.prototype.doSmth = function () { 
  console.log('doSmth from Second');
}

class Both extends First {
  constructor() {
    console.log('constructor of Both');
    super();
    Second.call(this);
  }

  doSmth: () => void
}

for (let key in Second.prototype) {
  Both.prototype[key] = Second.prototype[key];
}

class Final extends Both {
  doIt() {
    this.someMethod();
    this.doSmth();
    //Both.prototype.doSmth(); // ok
    //Final.prototype.doSmth(); // ok
  }
}
```

PS: Надо было гуглить не всяческие варианты с наследованием, а `typescript class prototype variable` - сразу нашёл подходящий вариант.